# How do you stop a php script from executing other scripts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Hi everyone, I have 4 parts of my code**

- 2 html buttons (Activate User, Delete User)
- a html table
- jquery on getting user_id on html table
- php script in executing update or delete sql command

**Scenario:**

I have a html table (the data are pulled from the SQL DB using a php script) I can select the rows on the table and extract their user_id flawlessly but the problem is that I have these two buttons (Activate User, Delete User) everything works well until you put their codes together the problem is that the activate php script takes command and not the delete user script. Is their a "break;" on php scripts just like switch cases so that it won't execute the other instead it executes the script specifically for those two buttons.

These are my buttons

```
<a type="button" id="activateUser"> Activate Selected User</a> 
<a type="button" id="deleteUser"> Delete Selected User</a>
```

This is the jQuery script for highlighting my html table row

```
<script>
     $('tr').click(function () 
     {
         $('tr').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected');
         selectedRow = $(this);

     });
```

This is the jQuery script for getting the id for my button and getting the user_id on **Activate Selected User** button.

```
$("#activateUser").click(function () 
{
   var td = $(selectedRow).children('td');
   for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
   window.location.href = window.location.href+'?id='+td[i].innerText;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
});
```

This is the jQuery script for getting the id for my button and getting the user_id on **Delete Selected User** button.

```
$("#deleteUser").click(function () 
{
   var td = $(selectedRow).children('td');
   for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
   window.location.href = window.location.href+'?id='+td[i].innerText;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
});
```

This is the **PHP SCRIPT** for activating the user by changing the user_active to 1 which **activates the user**

```
  <?php
      $id = $_GET['id']; //gets the user_id from as GET request 
      $btnQuery  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'";

      $buttonquery = mysqli_query($DBLink, $btnQuery);
      $Actcount = mysqli_num_rows($buttonquery);

      $act = 1;

      if($Actcount == 1)
      {


         $sqlact = "UPDATE users SET user_active='$act' WHERE 
         user_id='$id'";
         $activate = mysqli_query($DBLink, $sqlact);


         if($activate)
         {
            echo $ActivatedUser = "<b>Success!</b> User successfully Activated.";   
    echo "<script>setTimeout(function()
    {
      window.location.replace('http://localhost/webpage/manage-user.php');                                      
   }, 1500);    
    </script>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
         }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   ?>
```

This is the **PHP SCRIPT** for **deleting the selected user**

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $btnQuery  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'";

    $buttonquery = mysqli_query($DBLink, $btnQuery);
    delcount = mysqli_num_rows($buttonquery);

    if($delcount == 1)
    {
    $sqldel = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='$id'";
    $delete = mysqli_query($DBLink, $sqldel);

    if($delete)
    {
         echo $Deleted = "<b>Success!</b> User successfully Deleted.";
         echo "<script>setTimeout(function()
         {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            window.location.replace('http://localhost/webpage/manage-user.php');                                        
         }, 1500);</script>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }
}
?>
```

**THE CODE STRUCTURE**

 [ACTIVATE USER] BUTTON

 SCRIPT FOR SELECTING ROW IN HTML TABLE

 SCRIPT FOR GETTING THE user_id FOR USER ACTIVATION

 PHP SCRIPT ON ACTIVATING

 

 [DELETE USER] BUTTON

 SCRIPT FOR SELECTING ROW IN HTML TABLE

 SCRIPT FOR GETTING THE user_id FOR USER DELETION

 PHP SCRIPT ON DELETING

Again, it works well without the other half or vice versa, but when I try to combine them it never executes and it even executes only the first part or sometimes bugs. I tried using exit() or die() at the end of each php script but it makes matters worst.

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: It makes no sense to assign to `window.location.href` in a loop. Assigning to this variable redirects to a new page, and that stops the current script.

Comment: But the loop itself makes no sense. `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)` just iterates one time with `i = 0`.

Comment: thanks, but for now security is not yet my priority, i chose to redirect again since it displays ?id=1 in the url i want it to be clean and return to its current page without the get req. in the url.

Comment: @Dennis43 "_for now security is not yet my priority_" - security should **_ALWAYS_** be a priority. It's easier to do it right the first time than to go back and rewrite all of your code later to support the safer way to do it. Also, people tend to just keep telling themselves "I'll get to it later..." until it's too late. Trust me, it reminds me of me from a not-so-distant past. I became a **_MUCH_** better developer when I started making security a priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to your URL that indicates which action you want:

```
$("#activateUser").click(function () 
    {
       var td = $(selectedRow).children('td').first();
       window.location.href = window.location.href+'?action=activate&id='+$(td).text();
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
});
$("#deleteUser").click(function () 
    {
       var td = $(selectedRow).children('td').first();
       window.location.href = window.location.href+'?action=delete&id='+$(td).text();
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
});
```

Then in your PHP script you check `$_GET['action']`:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'activate') {
    // code for activating account
} elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'delete' {
    // code for deleting account
} else {
    die("Invalid action");
}
```